# Unable to grant DB2 privileges to my domain account

Tags: windows, dns, db2, privileges

I am unable to grant my primary work domain account the privileges to create database objects in DB2. Here is my current setup:

- OS is Windows 7 enterprise 64-bit
- DB2 version 9.7 Enterprise edition
- DB2 extended security was enabled during installation
- My domain account is member of the Administrators group as well as the DB2ADMNS and DB2USERS groups.
- The DB2ADMNS group is granted all authority privileges.
- DB2_GROUP_LOOKUP is set in the environment to LOCAL
- DB2 sysadm_group is set to DB2ADMNS

The DB2 instance has been restarted but my domain user still cannot create database objects like bufferpools. I created a local administrator account and added it to the DB2ADMNS and it was able to create the bufferpool objects.

I tried using the db2admin user to give all authorization privileges to my domain account in the DB2 control center but my domain account is not showing up in the drop down containing the users.

I removed the DB2_GROUP_LOOKUP environment variables and restarted the DB2 instance then tried to give my domain account user enough authorization privileges and now my domain account in showing up in the drop down. Once the changes are applied, I restarted the database instance and tried the bufferpool creation and it still fails.

Am I missing a configuration step in giving my user enough privileges? I need to have this configured as the IBM product I am installing fails if this privilege is not working. Thanks.

Comment: this might be a better question for http://serverfault.com or one of the IBM DB2 forums (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/im_forums.jspa)

Answer (score 0):

In 9.7 DB2ADMNS is not supposed to be able to access any data. SYSADM level accounts are reserved for maintenance tasks and should not be used for data access. Remove your connecting user from any special groups, and grant after that the proper access rights.